# How to upgrade existing ASP.NET application to ASP.NET vNext

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, upgrade

I have not been able to find any proper documentation on how to upgrade an ASP.NET application to ASP.NET vNext.

I would like to switch hosting servers and from what I have learnt, you can host ASP.NET vNext not only on Windows, but also on Linux, Mac, etc.

I found this article: [Upgrade to .NET vNext](http://carolynvanslyck.com/blog/2015/01/upgrade-to-net-vnext/) but it did not really help to achieve my goal.

So my question is: what are the important steps to take when upgrading an existing ASP.NET application to ASP.NET vNext?

Comment: You can certainly move forward the path you choose but remember msft say  "We don't provide the support for beta or CTP". See this https://blog.tonysneed.com/2015/05/25/develop-and-deploy-asp-net-5-apps-on-linux/

Answer (score 1):

ASP.NET 5 (vNext) is currently in beta, so you're not going to find much documentation as a lot of the available libraries are still changing. Likewise, the Kestrel HTTP server, for cross-platform hosting is also currently under development.  You can download the release candidate of Visual Studio 2015 [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/downloads/visual-studio-2015-downloads-vs.aspx) and play around with it yourself, but don't expect any official upgrade documentation until it's release.

Answer (score 0):

I believe there won't be a direct upgrade option. The architecture diverges so much it makes it impractical to 'upgrade' existing project into vNext.

It is easier if you rewrite your application instead.